# Wrong Forward Reference yet Scala script runs perfectly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, companion-object

I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ's Scala plugin and have this following piece of code, the aim of which is to allow enumeration of the instances of class `Count`:

```
class Count() {
  val id = Count.id()
  override def toString = s"Count$id"
}

object Count {
  var n = -1
  def id() = { n += 1; n }
}

println(Vector(new Count, new Count, new Count))
```

When referencing the method `id()` of the companion object, IntelliJ gives me a forward reference error, yet the script compiles perfectly, producing the output `Vector(Count0, Count1, Count2)`. In fact, I only noticed the error by chance, after running the script successfully. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala worksheets attempt to compile each instruction separately. 
If you wrap all your code into one object  (to force scala compiler work with whole code integrally) - there will be no such exception:

```
object a {

  class Count() {
    val id = Count.id()

    override def toString = s"Count$id"
  }

  object Count {
    var n = -1

    def id() = {
      n += 1; n
    }
  }

  println(Vector(new Count, new Count, new Count))

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an explanation about why the script itself runs despite the compile-time complaints?

Comment: Assume scala worksheets are recompiling all the time. At first time class `Count` failed to be compiled. But as soon as you defined `object Count` and it was compiled `class` was able to compile also and your println processed properly.